# specify the generic type of method arguments

Tags: java, generics

to extend my departments private Libary I tried to implement a isBetween method. This method is generic and expects a `Comparable` type `T` for its minimum value, its maximum value, and for an varargs values. Its purpose is to examine if all values are within the specified range.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(isBetween(1, 100, 200, 100, 1, 2));
  }


  @SafeVarargs
  public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isBetween(T minimum, T maximum, T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
      if (!(value.compareTo(minimum) >= 0 && value.compareTo(maximum) <= 0))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

This works just fine. But the type T can contain any Comparable objects. A method call:

```
System.out.print(isBetween(1, 100, 200, 100, "How awkward", 2));
```

would also be accepted at compile-time. 
This is not typesafe at all and can't be accepted.

Two solutions came into my mind:

***1. call the method like the following***

`System.out.print(Class.<Integer>isBetween(1, 100, 200, 100, 1, 2));`

***2. make one of my method parameters of type `U` and extend type `T` to type `U`***

Both "solutions" do not seem to be very elegant. The first one requires to write additional code before you call the method and the second one seems like a hack.

**Are there any more elegant ways to solve my problem?**

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`?

Comment: great this didn't came into my mind, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this can be easily fixed by [avoiding raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Let's look at your code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isBetween(T minimum, T maximum, T... values) {
    // ...
}
```

`T` is a nice and generic, but `Comparable` is a raw type. You want `Comparable<T>`, so your method should look like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isBetween(T minimum, T maximum, T... values) {
    // ...
}
```

and then `isBetween(1, 100, 200, 100, "How awkward", 2)` won't be possible anymore.

---

The `isBetween` method allows "equal" argument types if they have a equal super class which implements `Comparable`.

For example using `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` (user [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) had this good idea):

```
isBetween(new java.util.Date(1L), new java.util.Date(4L), new java.sql.Date(5L))
```

This will result in *"false"*, because the third argument is "greater", than the upper bound. And `java.sql.Date` is accepted, because it extends `java.util.Date` and will infer `T` with it as the "common parent class which implements `Comparable`".

Comment: However this will fail if your arguments are `java.sql.Date`s :)

Comment: @fge If the arguments are `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, then no, it also works. This method allows arguments which have a common super class, which also implements `comparable`.

Comment: @fge Or have I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: Well is there a way to fix this behavior. Is there a possibility to make this method absolute typesafe?

Comment: @TomWellbrock This already is type safe. If `A` extends `B`, then an instance of `A` can also be compared to an instance of `B` (like in the above example). Can you explain why you want to restrict that? I can understand this for unequal types, like apples and oranges or `int` and `String`, but not for child to parent.

Comment: There could be some issues by providing that option. But as you say thats the standart with comparing classes, the fault would be with my teammate who messes with the method. Example of an Issue: `class Customer.` , `creditDemandingCustomer extends Customer` , `unvalidCustomer extends Customer`

Comment: @TomWellbrock Ah ok, understand. When you have parent `A implements Comparable<A>` and `B` and `C` as childs with no other connection, then you can still use `B` and `C` in `isBetween`. The only way to prohibit this (that I can currently think of) is prohibiting this in overridden `compareTo` methods for each child class. But this won't result in problems during compile time. Maybe someone else has a great idea to handle this during compile time.

Comment: @TomWellbrock Btw I would call the method `areAllBetween` or `areAllInRange` so it is more clear, that each value needs to be in range defined by the first two arguments :P (just a note :)).

Answer (score 1):

Make it `<T extends Comparable<T>>`:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isBetween(T minimum, T maximum, T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
        if (!(value.compareTo(minimum) >= 0 && value.compareTo(maximum) <= 0))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this will fail at compile.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is to pass in a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead of requiring `T` to be `Comparable`:

```
public static <T> boolean isBetween(Comparator<? super T> comparator, 
        T minimum, T maximum, T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
        if (!(comparator.compare(value, minimum) >= 0 && 
                comparator.compare(value, maximum) <= 0)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This allows you compare the objects however you want, and they don't need to be `Comparable`.

You could also provide a similar method to the other answers to skip writing the `Comparator` when `T` is `Comparable`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isBetween(T minimum, 
        T maximum, T... values) {
    return isBetween(T::compareTo, minimum, maximum, values);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea with the comparator. The idea was to do a simple method for simple purposes but i can implement your extended method as well :)...sadly we work with java 7, I hope we recive the update soon

Comment: The java 8 sample does not work for me he cannot resolve the method

Comment: @TomWellbrock I have compiled it with eclipse and javac 1.8.0_51, both of these methods worked each time, but calling the comparator version gave me an error with javac. You may need to change the name of one of the methods. Which compiler version are you using?

Comment: Im using javac 1.8.0_74. IntelliJ dosent even want to build. It says: "Cannot resolve method isBetween(<method reference>,T,T,T[])"

Comment: heres the compile error: Error:(14, 12) java: method isBetween in class de.popken.Main cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T,T,T[]
  found: T::compareTo,T,T,T[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.lang.Object
    upper bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super java.lang.Object>,T

Comment: @TomWellbrock I've tried it with 1.8.0_74 and IntelliJ now, I see the same error but when I try to compile it it says "compilation completed succesfully" and it runs fine, so I geuss it could be a bug in IntelliJ

Comment: The error also goes away when I change one of the method names, so you may want to just do that.

Comment: Changed the name and it works like a miracle thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use Comparable < T > instead of raw Comparable. In this way, you will ensure that all instances of type T are of the same type and it will fail on compile.